# Behavior with sleep mode when moving many files

Tags: windows-7, sleep

I'm in the process of moving huge amounts of files over to my external hard disk so I can upgrade my Windows 7 PC to Windows 10. One of the folders apparently was over 100 GB big, so I let it move over night. When I woke up, my PC was in sleep mode, and the light on my external hard disk wasn't on.

I think everything was carried over just fine, maybe even before it went into sleep mode, but I just want to make sure nothing was lost. What is Windows 7's behavior in this situation? Does it go into sleep mode when files are being moved? If it does go into sleep mode in the middle of file transfer, would it continue where it left off or would it just stop and mess everything up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. When in sleep mode, your entire PC's components go to 'sleep' but just not the RAM. Notice as you wake up your PC after putting it to sleep, every process and in your case, downloading and copying just resumes from where it was left. What the computer does is that it stores all the ongoing process into the RAM before going to sleep. So when you return, you will get it as you left.
So for your answer, no. Computer 'pauses' the process when putting to sleep.